# How to protect libgdx function fromJson against bad input?

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I am in my app trying to load level which can be created by user and I want to protect my app against crash when it will get file with bad input. How should I do it?

This is my current code:

```
Json json = new Json();
json.setIgnoreUnknownFields(true);
JsonWorldValueCache jsonWrldCache = json.fromJson(JsonWorldValueCache.class, jsonWorld);
```

Comment: Add a `try-catch`? Please clarify what you mean by *protect my app against crash when it will get file with bad input*, by posting enough code to reproduce the problem(s).

Comment: Thank you try&catch solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach the problem on two fronts:

First, you can surround the `Json#fromJson()` call with a try-catch statement as @Elliott suggested. If you catch an exception, politely tell the player that there is something wrong with the level they created, and ask them if they want to try loading it again (presumably after they've fixed it) or go back.

Second, you can provide the user with a level editor so they don't have to modify the JSON file directly. While this won't remove the possibility of failure (users are pretty good at breaking things), it will remove the majority of issues since your editor can ensure the proper structures and values are adhered to in the level file.